# Evaluate $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-e^{\sin x \ln \cos x}}{x^3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, derivatives

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{1-e^{\sin x \ln \cos x}}{x^3}.$$

So

$$\frac{1-e^{\sin x \ln \cos x}}{x^3} = \frac{e^{\sin x \ln \cos x[\cos x \ln \cos x-\frac{\sin^2(x)}{\cos x}]}}{3x^2}.$$
I can't continue from here.

Comment: Since $\sin x=x+O(x^2)$ and $\ln\cos x=-\frac12x^2+O(x^3)$, so we have $\sin x\ln\cos x=-\frac12x^3+O(x^4)$.

Comment: I solved using that but now I want to use only Lo'hpital for solving.

Comment: @Kenta S Why is there $O(x^4)$?.Shouldn't it be $O(x^3)$?

Comment: @VardanDanielyan it should be $O(x^4)$ (or alternatively, $o(x^3)$).

Comment: **Lo'hpital $=$ L'Hospital**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me solve/state some other limits for you, which you can use to figure yours out:

1. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x - 1}{x} = 1$$
2. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$
3. $$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\ln \cos x}{x^2} = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-\tan x}{2x} = \frac{-1}{2}$$

Now, write
$$\frac{1 - e^{\sin x \ln \cos x}}{x^3} = \frac{1 - e^{\sin x \ln \cos x}}{\sin x\ln\cos x} \cdot \frac{\sin x}{x} \cdot \frac{\ln\cos x}{x^2}$$
I hope you can take it from here.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Consider multiplying and dividing by $\sin x \ln(\cos x)$, splitting into three different limits and applying L'Hôspital rule separately on all three.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Taylor's expansions at order $3$:

- $\sin x=x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)$.
- $\cos x=1-\dfrac{x^2}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)$, so $\ln(\cos x)=-\dfrac{x^2}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)$.

Therefore
$$\sin x\ln(\cos x)=\Bigl(x-\dfrac{x^3}6+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)\Bigr)\Bigl(-\dfrac{x^2}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)\Bigr)=-\dfrac{x^3}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr),$$
and  by composition with the expansion of the exponential:
$$1-e^{\sin x \ln(\cos x)}=1-\Bigl(-\frac{x^3}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr)\Bigr)=\frac{x^3}2+o\bigl(x^3\bigr),$$
which shows the numerator is equivalent to $\frac{x^3}2$, so that
$$\frac{1-e^{\sin x \ln(\cos x)}}{\,x^3\,}\sim_0\frac{\cfrac{x^3}2}{x^3}=\frac12.$$

Answer (score 0):

We can avoid L'Hospital's and Taylor Series for the toughest part of the problem as follows:

$$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(\cos x)}{x^2}=-\dfrac12\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1-\sin^2x)}{-\sin^2x}\cdot\left(\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x\right)^2$$

Now use $\lim_{y\to0}\dfrac{\ln(1+y)}y=1$